# Добавление элементов в массив из запроса

Tags: java, rest-assured

Есть GET запрос на получение списка городов. Но список элементов ограничен пагинацией страницы в количестве 100. Всего страниц 15.

Как сделать так, чтобы добавить в массив все элементы, отправляя один запрос с разным параметром page от 1 до 15?

```
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given ().relaxedHTTPSValidation 
        ().auth ().oauth2 (accessToken ())
        .param ("format", "json")
        .param ("page", "1")
        .param ("per_page", "100")
        .param ("fields", "id");

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream (path);
        Properties properties = new Properties ();
        properties.load (fileInputStream);

        Response response = request.get (properties.getProperty 
        ("getCities"));
        int statCode = response.getStatusCode ();
        String statLine = response.getStatusLine ();
        String contType = response.getContentType ();
        ResponseBody responseBody = response.getBody ();
        String responseBodyAsString = responseBody.asString ();
        JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath ();

        Assert.assertEquals (statCode, 200);
        Assert.assertEquals (statLine, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        Assert.assertEquals (contType, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        Assert.assertTrue (responseBodyAsString.contains ("id"));

        ArrayList <Integer> cities = new ArrayList <> ();
        cities.addAll ((jsonPath.get ("id")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать нечто подобное:

```
String[] pages = new String[15];
for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    RestAssured.given()
        ...
        .param("page", i)
        ...
        .get("endpoint");

    ...
    String responseBodyAsString = responseBody.asString ();
    pages[i-1] = responseBodyAsString;
    ...
}
```

При завершении цикла ваш массив будет заполнен ответами от сервера с разными страницами (15, как указано в вопросе). Массив можно заменить на `List` при необходимости.